# ASP.NET Application Performance of HTML References

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, project, solution

Quick question regarding scripts and html.

In a html file, would there be a difference speed wise (although it might be minor) in the following two examples if I included a JavaScript script using:

```
<script src="http://localhost:56090/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

The first one includes a script from a different project in the same ASP.NET solution, whereas the second one uses a script from the same project as the html file.

What would be the difference?

On a side note (but kind of related), how do the projects of a solutions relate to each other, are they compiled into a single application domain or are they separate applications but linked to each other?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

no difference

as

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

is **compiled** into the correct string...

The **view is compiled anyway** regardless of the ~

The the difference in time **is basically unmeasureable in c#**...
 so you wouldn't be able to tell using convention tools if there was actually a difference.... we are probably talking about nanoseconds here or smaller.

so its better to use

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

than hard coding any values.

Advantage is that the base url is dynamic/relative to what the site is.
i.e. if you hard coded localhost... you are going to have Huge issues when you try and deploy this to an actual url. e.g. www.mycoolwebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

Client-side there is *zero* difference.  Both get emitted to fully-qualified URLs (possibly even the exact same URL, depending on what `~` resolves to) and the client sees no difference between the two.

Server-side there is a *tiny* difference because ASP.NET needs to translate `~` into a path.  That's a very optimized, very fast operation.  You shouldn't notice a difference.  But if you're at a scale where you really need to squeeze every millisecond possible (like, Google-scale), this adds a millisecond.

In all likelihood you should use whichever makes the most logical sense for your application needs.  The performance difference is negligible.

Comment: After caching.... who knows? views are complied... usually once as far as i know. Also if these pages are compiled anyway regardless of '~' or not... we are really talking about nanoseconds rather than millisecond i would think.

Comment: @Seabizkit: Possibly.  "a millisecond" was really just a random value to demonstrate the scale of the difference.  It's a non-zero difference, but in the vast majority of cases an unimportant one.

Comment: totally get you... I was just illustrating the point that it is much much smaller of a difference.... as, if you were really trying to squeeze every bit you can... it is almost impossible to measure nanoseconds in c# where as you can millisecond.... so trying to change this for performance reasons becomes basically unmeasurable, hence why i say there is no difference, advantages out-way performance any day of the week.. as the performance diff is so small it **can not be measured accurately**.

Comment: @Seabizkit: Agreed, at least in the vast majority of cases.  At scale, small numbers become large numbers. For example, Google has invested considerable effort in removing *every byte possible* from their home page. A single byte, that many times per second, is a noticeable aggregate cost. It is, however, very unlikely that the OP is working at such scale.

Comment: @Seabizkit: (Anecdote: Someone once calculated the amount of energy consumed globally by the fact that Google was using a white background instead of a black background back in the days of CRT monitors when white colors used more power than black. For one monitor it was negligible. In aggregate, it was *astounding*.)